# C++ convert character array to uppercase ( no MFC )

Tags: c++, keypress, uppercase, character-arrays

I am trying to get my application to convert a character array to uppercase letter so I can pass them as key presses. I know I am close to getting this code working but I just cant see the problem.

```
            int a, b, c, d;
        char text[25];
        char upper[25];

        for (a = 0, b = sizeof(login); a < b; a++)
        {
            if (isalpha(login[a])){
                l[a] = toupper(login[a]);
                Sleep(1000);
                GenerateKey(l[a], FALSE);}
            else{
                GenerateKey(l[a], FALSE);
                Sleep(1000);
                l[a] = login[a];}
        }
        login[a]='\0';
        GenerateKey(0x09, FALSE);

        for (c = 0, d = sizeof(pass); c < d; c++)
        {
            if (isalpha(pass[c])){
                p[c] = toupper(pass[c]);
                GenerateKey(p[c], FALSE);
                Sleep(1000);}
            else{
                GenerateKey(p[c], FALSE);
                p[c] = pass[c];
                Sleep(1000);}
        }
        pass[a]='\0';

        GenerateKey(0x09, FALSE);
        Sleep(1000);
        GenerateKey(0x09, FALSE);
        Sleep(1000);
        GenerateKey(0x0D, FALSE);
```

And here is the GenerateKey function:

```
void GenerateKey(int vk, BOOL bExtended) {

KEYBDINPUT  kb = {0};
INPUT       Input = {0};

/* Generate a "key down" */
if (bExtended) { kb.dwFlags  = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY; }
kb.wVk  = vk;
Input.type  = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.ki  = kb;
SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));

/* Generate a "key up" */
ZeroMemory(&kb, sizeof(KEYBDINPUT));
ZeroMemory(&Input, sizeof(INPUT));
kb.dwFlags  =  KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
if (bExtended) { kb.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY; }
kb.wVk = vk;
Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.ki = kb;
SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(Input));

return;
 }
```

Any help would be great!

**EDIT:**

This appplication is trying to open a webpage and then enter login information and press submit(using tab to select the username, password fields, etc). To answer @Rup, `l[]` and `p[]` are initialised above this block of code.

```
        char l[180];
        char p[180];
```

l is the users login name and p is their password. I am trying to convert these to uppercase to pass them in GenerateKey. eg `GenerateKey('A', FALSE);`

At the moment the code does not seem to pass any keypresses at all but the application freezes so I believe it is getting stuck in a for loop somewhere.

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks to @William for providing the helpful code.
Using the toUpper function I am very close to solving this issue. The only issue I am having now is that the login and password being passed contain extra characters. For example if I pass login as `username`, then rerun the program and pass login as `user` I get the output `userame`.

This is the code I have now with the GenerateKey and toUpper functions:

```
            // Convert to uppercase to be passed as keypresses
        toUpper(login, sizeof(login));
        toUpper(pass, sizeof(pass));
        int a;
        for(a=0; a<sizeof(login);a++){
            GenerateKey(login[a], FALSE);}
        login[a]='\0';
        GenerateKey(0x09, FALSE);
        a=0;
        for(a=0; a<sizeof(pass);a++){
            GenerateKey(pass[a], FALSE);}
        pass[a]='\0';
        GenerateKey(0x09, FALSE);
        Sleep(1000);
        GenerateKey(0x09, FALSE);
        Sleep(1000);
        GenerateKey(0x0D, FALSE);
```

**SOLUTION:**

Using `strlen(login);` in the above code cleared up all hte issues I was having.

Comment: In your not isalpha case you're using `l[a]` uninitialised. But you'll need to give us more detail about what is / isn't working - are you able to debug this at all? And are login[] ASCII characters or VK codes? You appear to be mixing the two.

Comment: And what exactly is the question?

Comment: Apologies, I have edited my question to provide more information.

Comment: please give a minimal compilable example, including a main(), showing the error.

Comment: Thanks - but that's declaring l[a] not initialising it. (There's no implicit init-to-0 unless they're global variables.) My point was you're calling `GenerateKey(l[a], FALSE);` before the line that sets `l[a]`. You should be able to identify where it's hanging in the debugger.

Comment: @Rup You are correct, however I have adopted Williams function to make the code a little neater. I am still having trouble with the keys being passed though. The detail has been added to the question .

Comment: Last edit: because you're emitting the whole of the login array. You should stop the first time you read a 0.

Comment: @Rup. Sorry but I don't really follow what your saying. By using `login[a]='0';` It just seems to cut off 1 character from the older, longer login and print the rest.

Comment: Ah, I have solved the problem. `sizeof(login)` was not working in this case. Instead using `strlen(login)` provides the correct length and solves the problem.

Comment: Yes - either that or `for(a=0; (login[a] != 0) && (a<sizeof(login)); a++)` would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the Issue with the following code:

The code is explained in the comments.

```
        // Convert to uppercase to be passed as keypresses
        toUpper(login, sizeof(login));
        toUpper(pass, sizeof(pass));
        int a;
        // Loop through the character array and send the key presses
        for(a=0; a<strlen(login);a++){
            GenerateKey(login[a], FALSE);}
        GenerateKey(0x09, FALSE);
        for(a=0; a<strlen(pass);a++){
            GenerateKey(pass[a], FALSE);}
        // Additional keypresses
        GenerateKey(0x09, FALSE);
        Sleep(1000);
        GenerateKey(0x09, FALSE);
        Sleep(1000);
        GenerateKey(0x0D, FALSE);
```

The GenerateKey function and toUpper functions provided are also needed in order for this code to function correctly.

Thank you for all your help on this Issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
void toUpper(char* pArray, int arrayLength)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
    {
        if(pArray[i] >= 'a' && pArray[i] <= 'z')
            pArray[i] -= ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: please do something like this: `pArray[i] >= 'a' && pArray[i] <= 'z')`, and similar for the assignment.

Comment: Thanks for this code. I am still having a small issue though. I have updated my original question with the details.